# Why is my code for saving an image to user defaults only working some of the time? Swift

Tags: swift

After selecting an image from camera roll, then placing it into an image view, I need to save it to user defaults.

All the code is working, but not reliably, it works maybe 3 out of 5 times.

I believe the problem is the code that adds the image into the array is not great.

I'm very new to Swift and I have no idea how to clean it up, can anyone help please?

Here is my code

```
class importImageViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    var importImage = UIImage()

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBOutlet weak var saveScreenButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var importImageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    @IBAction func importButton(_ sender: Any) {

         let image = UIImagePickerController()

         image.delegate = self

         image.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary

         image.allowsEditing = false

         self.present(image, animated: true)
         {
             //on completion

         }
     }
      // I THINK THE PROBLEM IS IN HERE BUT I CANT SEE IT

     func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
         if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
         {
            importImageView.image = image

            if case importImageView.image = image {

                importImage = image
           }
         }
         else
         {

         }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

     }




    func saveImage()
      {

            //encode image to user defaults
                     let imageData:NSData = importImage.pngData()! as NSData

           //save image to user defaults
                     UserDefaults.standard.set(imageData, forKey: "screenShotImage")

       }


    @IBAction func saveScreenButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        saveImage()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `if case importImageView.image = image` ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson   After selecting an image in camera roll and puting into an image view, and I know before I save it to user defaults I have to place it into an array and thats what that code is doing ... funny things is, I know its wrong but it works (sort of)

Comment: I only asked about that specific piece of code

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that code is mean to place the image into the array.  sorry

Comment: @Geno is not a good practice to save large file to `UserDefaults`, you should use `FileManager` for internal storage

Comment: @toto yes i am aware of this, I only need to save a single image into this so i decided to go this way instead of core data. thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Geno He did not say to save it using core data. Save it inside your app bundle. Saving your image inside a plist it is definitely a bad idea. Even worst as PNG data representation (I wouldn't save as JPEG either which the data is significantly smaller).

Comment: Note that when saving your data inside UserDefaults property list it will need to be base64 encoded which will even increase its size.

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you for the advice, the reason I mentioned core data is at present that the only other saving Ive done ... I dont know what saving in the App bundle is .. YET !! .. again thanks very much for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use `Data` instead of `NSData` in `saveImage()`

```
func saveImage() {
    let imageData = importImage.pngData()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(imageData, forKey: "screenShotImage")
}
```

Now, try fetching the `image` from `UserDefaults` in `viewDidLoad()` and set it as `importImageView's` `image`,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let data = defaults.data(forKey: "screenShotImage"), let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        importImage = image
        importImageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Also, modify the `imagePickerController(_: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` definition to,

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        importImageView.image = image
        importImage = image
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Im fetching the image on a different view controller, on this VC I need to select an image form camera roll and then save it to user defaults ... the saving code works fine on a different VC when the image is already in an array.  but thank you for cleaning that code also ...

Comment: The code is working fine for me in both saving and fetching cases.

Comment: PGDev, I have adjusted all the code to your and its working but in the same way as before, its intermittent.  Im saving the image into defaults and then rerunning the simulator and on the entry VC (a different VC) thats where the fetch is in viewdidload, its working 3 out of 5 times .. any ideas?

Comment: thanks a lot, Ive tried it on a real device and It fine every time ... maybe a simulator issue ?  as my skill grow ill clean the code more ...

Comment: @Geno don't save data to the UserDefaults. You should only store your app UI state on it or very light content. If you need to persist an image save it straight to your application support or documents directory and save its file name if you need to UserDefaults. If you need to load the image again reconstruct your URL and load it from there.